# Rxjs Subject#next asynchronous or not?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Hi I wonder if the following code does execute in sequence? i.e. whether the logging "*Worker has finished task C*" does always happen after the logging "*Finished 3 task(s)*"?

Long question: with the `scan` operator, I can be sure the tasks are executed in sequence, that I am not worried. What worries me is I want from the last subscribe to do something only after task C has completed and I am not sure if the position of where `o.complete()` is put guarantees that. e.g. will `start()` runs `do.("A") -> do.("B") -> do.("C")` without waiting for the scans to complete and runs `o.complete()` straight away, giving an output:

```
Worker has finished task C
Doing task A
Finished 1 task(s)
Doing task B
Finished 2 task(s)
Doing task C
Finished 3 task(s)
```

If that can be the case, how do you fix the code so that achieves what I have described?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xhhwme

```
class Worker {
  private tasks: Subject<string>;
  public init(): Observable<number> {
    this.tasks = new Subject<string>();
    return this.tasks.scan((count, task) => {
      console.log("Doing task " + task);
      return ++count;
    }, 0).asObservable();
  }
  public do(task: string): void {
    this.tasks.next(task);
  }
}

function start(worker: Worker): Observable<void> {
  return Observable.create(o => {
    const monitor = worker.init();
    monitor.subscribe(c => console.log("Finished " + c + " task(s)"));
    worker.do("A");
    worker.do("B");
    worker.do("C");
    o.complete();
    worker.do("D");
  });
}

const worker = new Worker();
start(worker).subscribe({
  complete: () => console.log("Worker has finished task C")
});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

TLDR: `Subject.next` is synchronous.

Reactive streams are synchronous if the source is synchronous, unless you explicitly make them asynchronous or mix them with asynchronous streams. None of that happens in your code. Some examples:

```
//Synchronous
of(1,2)
  .subscribe(console.log);

//asynchronous because of async source
interval(1000)
  .subscribe(console.log);

//aynchronous because one stream is async (interval)
of(1,2)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(x => interval(1000).pipe(take(2)))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);

//async because we make it async
of(1,2, asyncScheduler)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

What happens in your example? Everything inside `Observable.create` will be executed immediately. When you call `worker.do("A");` then `this.tasks.next(task);` emits a new value and the `tasks` stream chain is executed (synchronously). The same happens with `B` and `C`.

When you call `o.complete();` the `start(worker)` stream completes and `"Worker has finished task C"` is printed. Then `D` is executed by the `tasks` stream.

You can find more extensive information on asynchronous / synchronous behavior in these articles:

- [Concurrency and Asynchronous Behavior with RxJS](https://itnext.io/concurrency-and-asynchronous-behavior-with-rxjs-11b0c4b22597)
- [Reactive Streams and Multithreading](https://itnext.io/reactive-streams-and-multithreading-efd63b67de9a)

Comment: This is the prefect example of what SO answers should be. Not only addressed the issues and provided relevant further study materials. You can be a real good teacher, thank you!