# Read data from ngrx store directly

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I saw in our codebase a lot of places using this pattern

```
getUrl() : string {
    let url = ''
    this.store.pipe(selectorConfig, take(1)).subscribe((config) => {
        url = config.url
    });
    return url;
}
```

Just want to check if this is async? will the selectorConfig emit only when config changes so this is an async call? There are also someone saying ngrx store is a behaviourObject so the moment you subscribe, it emits last value so this effectively is a sync function.

Could anyone confirm which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you make it asynchronous it's a synchronous operation. As is the `Subject.next` method.

```typescript
// Synchronous
getUrl() : string {
  let url = ''
  console.log('START');
  // considering that selectorConfig does not contain anything `asynchronous`, which it should not
  this.store.pipe(selectorConfig, take(1)).subscribe((config) => {
    url = config.url
    console.log('URL:', config.url);
  });
  console.log('END');
  return url;
}
/* OUTPUT
START
URL: <yourUrl>
END
*/

// Asynchronous
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

getUrl() : string {
  let url = ''
  console.log('START');
  // adding a delay operator makes it asynchronous
  this.store.pipe(selectorConfig, delay(0), take(1)).subscribe((config) => {
    url = config.url
    console.log('URL:', config.url);
  });
  console.log('END');
  return url;
}
/* OUTPUT
START
END
URL: <yourUrl>
*/
```

There's a nice explanation to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078374/rxjs-subjectnext-asynchronous-or-not)